# what is energy and power of a signal having different values at different time?

Tags: signal, signal-processing

[image]

I have attached the question . Its question no. 3 b) Basically I have to find power and energy of a signal . But the signal 
Has different value for different time. Like for 0

Comment: Energy is watt-seconds , power is watts.

Comment: Have you ever heard about "integration"? Can you calculate the definite integral of a function?

Comment: I am not talking about integral of the function . For finding power of the signal I have to integrate the square of the mod of signal from infinite to - infinite

Comment: so do that. am i missing something here. (thats actually the energy of the signal). You dont actually even need to integrate, you can just do it by looking at it.

Comment: Also, it looks like it's sort of a trick question, in that the power is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding average power you have to integrate the square of mod of signal from -infinity to infinity. You can break the definite integral in 4 parts : -infinity to -2, -2 to 0, 0 to 2 and 2 to +infinity.  Just put the corresponding value of X(t) in each definite integral and evaluate.